# How to delete/hide div class in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Conbix theme and I want to delete/hide this section. How can I do it with CSS ?

Class name is  `about__one-left-experience`

I tried something but did not work. I need help.

If you want to check the [website](https://gururbatuhanayaz.com/).

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.about__one-left-experience {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.about__one.dark__image .lg-mb-30 {display: none;}
```

There are better ways to do it like:

```
.about__one-left {
    display: none;
}
```

But in this way it will only be hidden but will still occupy the space and because of that the right side content will be on the right.